# Special callback handling with C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, callback, marshalling

I have a C++ dll, which defines a set of callback function. This functions are called somewhere in the C++ dll. To handle this callbacks, the other side must overwrite these functions. So the C++ dll implements an exported function, which returns the function pointer for all of the callback functions.

**The C++ code (parts of it)**

The C++ code looks like this:

```
// typedefs
typedef int FInt;
typedef const char* FString;

// Pointers to CB functions.
void  (CALLINGCONV *sOutputCB)(FInt pMode, FString pMsg, FString pSys);
```

In some functions the C++ dll uses this as (GOutputLevel is also int):

```
void DWindowsOutput::output(GOutputLevel pLevel, const string &pSys, 
  const char *pMsg) 
{
   if (sOutputCB != 0)
    sOutputCB(pLevel, pSys.c_str(), pMsg);
}
```

To implement this callback in calling applications, the C++ dll exports an function defined as:

```
long CALLINGCONV dGetCBAddr(const char *pCBName)
{
    ...
    if (!strcmp(pCBName, "fOutputCB"))
      return (long)&sOutputCB;    
}
```

**The basic stuff**

On the caller side, after loading and mapping the dll funcs, all callbacks are declared as forwarded functions and then we assign to the function pointers the results of dGetCBAddr.
After that, all the functions are called in the dll, using the delphi implementation.

In Delphi (the original code) this looks like this:

```
// type defs
type
  FString = PAnsiChar;
  FInt = Integer;
// callback forward
procedure fOutputCB(pMode: FInt; pSys, pMsg: FString); stdcall; forward;
// initialize GF CallBacks
// NOTE: the dll is loaded and dGetCBAddr is assigned with GetProcAdress!
procedure GF_CB_Initialize;

  procedure loadCB(pAdrPtr: Pointer; const pAdrName: String);
  var
    tPtr: Pointer;
  begin
    tPtr := IFAPI.dGetCBAddr(FString(AnsiString(pAdrName)));
    if Assigned(tPtr) then Pointer(tPtr^) := pAdrPtr;
  end;

begin
  loadCB(@fOutputCB,'fOutputCB');
  ...
end;

// callbacks
procedure fOutputCB(pMode: FInt; pSys, pMsg: FString);
begin
  // do something in delphi with the dll callback
end;
```

My problems are:

1. How to get Pointer(tPtr^) := pAdrPtr; to work in C#?
2. Forward declarations are not supported in C# i guess, so i used delegates.

**The c# try**

Now to the c# part i tested (and instructed by google search):

First i defined an delegate function and an member of this type.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public delegate void fOutputCB(int pMode, string pSys, string pMsg);
public static fOutputCB mOutputCB; // member to avoid GC cleansup
```

Here is the method which should be called (test for me):

```
private void OutputCB(int pMode, string pSys, string pMsg)
        {
            string tSys = pSys;
            string tMsg = pMsg;
            int tMode = pMode;
        }
```

Then i implemented in an method the loading stuff. For the C++ Dll i used WinAPI LoadLibrary etc. Here i create the member, give the wanted called method as parameter and try to assign the assign the function pointer from the C++ DLL.

```
mOutputCB = new fOutputCB(OutputCB);
IntPtr tOutputCBPtr = drvGetCBAddr("OutputCB");
if (tOutputCBPtr != null)
  tOutputCBPtr = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(mOutputCB);
```

drvGetCBAddr is the C# pendant of dGetCBAddr:

All compiles and runs fine, so long, but the callbacks are not working. I guess that one simple step is missing on the C# side. I tried to use managed code so far, but could be 
i must use unsafe code.

Comment: I don't understand your logic exactly, but it looks like these two strings are not the same: `"fOutputCB"` and `"OutputCB"`. May this be a reason?

Comment: "Not working" is a hopeless diagnostic, the mysterious "FString" and how an "FInt" could morph into a "GOutputLevel" do not help either.  You'll need to do the legwork to debug your code.  Enable unmanaged debugging in your C# project so you can set breakpoints in your native code to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok i forgot the typedefs, i edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assigning the tOutputCBPtr variable with the new function pointer will not work, you must write the new function pointer value to the address of "sOutputCB" which is returned by drvGetCBAddr.

```
IntPtr tOutputCBPtr = drvGetCBAddr("OutputCB");
if (tOutputCBPtr != null)
    Marshal.WriteIntPtr(tOutputCBPtr, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(mOutputCB));
```